# Android radio button click already checked button

Tags: android

I've got an activity that lets users choose a "type" of a thing using radio buttons, but when modifying that thing I want to pre-check the radio button for the type the thing already is, and allow the user to click that checked radio button *again* if they don't want to change the type before moving to the next activity. I want to pre-check because users might not remember which type the thing was when they go to modify it.

The problem is that the listener only triggers when the option *changes*, not when the user clicks the option that's already checked. That makes sense, seeing as the listener is called "OnCheckedChangeListener," but when I try adding an OnClick listener to catch the click of a checked button, nothing happens. It simply doesn't trigger, and I don't see any other listeners on the RadioGroup object that seem like they'd do what I want.

Here's the checked change listener, which works fine:

```
rgThingType.setOnCheckedChangeListener { radioGroup, i ->
    val checkedRadioButton = radioGroup?.findViewById(i) as? RadioButton
    when(checkedRadioButton?.id) {
        // ...
    }
    goToActivity()
}
```

And here's the on click listener, which never triggers no matter what:

```
rgThingType.setOnClickListener {
    goToActivity()
}
```

Now, I can add an OnClick to each radio button to accomplish this, ie:

```
rbThingType1.setOnClickListener {
    thingType = 1
    if(/* extra logic to prevent double activity start */) {
        goToActivity()
    }
}
```

but that is awkward and seems like an anti-pattern, given I already have the checked change listener, and in fact it screws things up as it causes the next activity to be triggered twice since both listeners get called, forcing me to keep/check extra state to avoid. Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with this whole pre-checking thing. Doesn't the user know what type is selected because it's written next to the selected RadioButton? Also, I feel like a Submit button would be better than tapping a RadioButton to launch another Activity.

Comment: The user doesn't know unless I tell them, either by pre-checking the option or by putting some other visual indicator next to it. From a previous activity, they click a "Modify" button/action that takes them to this activity, and they might need a reminder of which type of thing this was. I considered using a "submit" button instead of instantly taking you to the next activity after selecting a new thing type, but it's really an unnecessary extra click that I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);     
radioGroup.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    // get selected radio button from radioGroup
                    int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    // find the radiobutton by returned id
                    radioButton =  findViewById(selectedId);
                    String slectedValue=radioButton.getText()          
    });
```